# jQuery - onClick of nested text-field hover containing <li> dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, click, hover, html-lists, textfield

I have 2 username/password text fields inside of `<li>`.  On `:hover` of the `<li>` the drop down appears showing the text fields. When the user clicks on the text fields, I want the `<li>` to have the pseudo class `:hover` so the the fields remain visible if the mouse is moved outside of the contianing `<li>`.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
<script>$('#username').on('click',function() {
    $('#li').trigger('hover');});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<li id="li"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
   <p>Or Login Below</p>
 <form method="post" action="#" name="loginform" id="loginform" class="myClass">
<fieldset>
    <input value="username" type="text" name="username" id="username" onclick="this.value=''" class="left" />
    <input value="password" type="password" name="password" id="password" onclick="this.value=''" class="left" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login2" value="Login" />
</fieldset>
</form>  
</li>
```

Is the JavaScript wrong or is it possibly conflicting with other JavaScript?
Also, would it be easy to make it so 'clicking of the `<div>` makes the `:hover` go away, thus hiding the `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going about this wrong. Apparently CSS psuedo-selectors cannot be selected the way I was trying.
Here is an explanation for anyone else http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover

This ended up working:

```
<script>$('#username').click(function() {
$('#li').addClass('psuedoClassProperty'); // adds the CSS to display
```

});

and to hide when clicked off: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

```
<script>
$('html').click(function() {
$('#li').removeClass('psuedoClassProperty');
});
$('#li').click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried this code but it doesn't work

Not sure what is "not working" but I would implement the behavior differently:

Triggering 'hover' on click doesn't seem right to me. Code will become fuzzy if the 'hover state' doesn't mean the mouse is hovering of an element.

The code will be more readable/logic to just toggle the visibility of the LI on the click event.

```
$('#username').on('click',function() {
    $('#li').toggle();
});
```

Comment: "not working" means it doesn't do what I want it to;  nothing happens

Comment: which is what exactly?

Comment: When I click on the the text-field  and mouse away the drop-down disappears.

Comment: then I would go for my suggested solution: do not use hover state for non-hovering situations: explicitly hide/show the element.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is completely wrong. This hides the drop-down area and makes it so it won't come back. Try it yourself, make a fiddle!

Comment: euh, you are asking (demanding) your helpers to make a fiddle? Well stackoverflow newbie, good luck find your answer (from someone else).